# Model is only updated in the Django Administration app and not in my app

Tags: python, django

I have just noticed that the model that I am displaying in my app is only showing new items that have been entered in the Django Administration app, and isn't showing anything that I enter directly from my own application. Could anyone explain what is going on?

Here is my models.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Ticket(models.Model):
    """
    Add a ticket
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225,blank=False)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and here is my admin.py in the same app:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Ticket

admin.site.register(Ticket)
```

and here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from tickets.models import Ticket

class TicketsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'image', 'published_date']
```

and views.py:

```
def ticket_detail(request,pk):
    """
    Create a view that will return a single ticket object based on the ticket id 
    and render it to the 'show_tickets.html' template
    """
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket,pk=pk) 
    ticket.views +=1
    ticket.save()
    return render(request, "ticketdetail.html", {'ticket':ticket})

def create_or_edit_ticket(request, pk=None):
    """
    Create a view that allows us to create or edit a ticket depending if 
    the tickets id is null or not. 
    """
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=pk) if pk else None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TicketsForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=ticket)
        if form.is_valid():
            ticket = form.save()
            return redirect(ticket_detail, ticket.pk)
    else:
        form = TicketsForm(instance=ticket)
    return render(request, "issuetrackerticketform.html", {'form':form})
```

the actual form that is used to enter a new ticket:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Add Issues</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="col-md-12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form | as_bootstrap }}
        <a href="{% url 'get_tickets' %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>Create Issue</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How do you enter this in your own application?

Comment: I have updated my first post to include the forms.py and views.py

Comment: And how do you make a request, how does the `<form>` look like?

Comment: I have just added the html for the form.

Comment: you use a link (`<a href="">`) instead of a button that makes the post request (`<button type="submit">`), you need to *submit* the form.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved the problem and is probably something I wouldn't have ever found! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making use of a link (`<a href="…">…</a>`), you will make a GET request to the view to that link, not submit the form with a POST request to the view. You thus should submit the form, for example with `<button type="submit">…</button>`):

```
<form method="POST" class="col-md-12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form | as_bootstrap }}
    <button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>Create Issue</button>
</form>
```